# How do I split a string and add all the split into ONE long column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with one column and multiple rows. Each row contains the lyrics to one song with lines split by "\n", What I have so far is

```
with open('Lyrics_Pavement.json') as json_data:
data = json.load(json_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data['songs'])
df1 = df.lyrics.str.split(pat="\n")
```

df1 then contains a 1 column dataframe with the lyrics having \n removed and surrounded by '[]'.

```
1    [It's the shouting, it's the shouting, It's the Dutchman, it's the Dutchman shout, Get it away, I don't need your shaft, It's the shouting, it's the shouting, It's the shouting, it's the Dutchman shout, Give it away, I don't need your shaft, (yes I do), It's the shouting, it's the shouting, It's the shouting, it's the Dutchman shout, Get it away, I don't need your shaft]
```

That is an example of row 1. How would I get the data to appear as such:

```
It's the shouting,
It's the shouting,
It's the dutchman
```

and so on. Each new line above would be one row of a dataframe. And then for row 2, append those same lyrics to that dataframe.

Thanks!

edit:
the original data looks like this

```
    0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
1  It's the shouting, it's the shouting\nIt's the Dutchman, it's the Dutchman shout\nGet it away, I don't need your shaft\nIt's the shouting, it's the shouting\nIt's the shouting, it's the Dutchman shout\nGive it away, I don't need your shaft\n(yes I do)\nIt's the shouting, it's the shouting\nIt's the shouting, it's the Dutchman shout\nGet it away, I don't need your shaft                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
2  Everybody's going out tonight\nAnd everybody's hanging out tonight, it's alright\nListen to them show when they learn how to lie\nYou can sing along with them if you try\nHolding the spoken world up\nI need it, I need it, I need it\nShe's got a neck like a Saturday paper\nYou read it fast before the Sunday mass\nTake it back it's nothing\nIt's nothing like it talks\nDon't listen to me baby if you wanna survive\nYou did it, you did it, you did it wrong\nCollapse, it's evident to me\nTonight all the friends are strangers\nI'd like to take my story\nTo some place the don't know me\nCreatures come out of the bars\nTalk is small but you talk to Paul\nSold sex on Bird Cage walk\nBoys are drinking and on the docks\nUnion man, I'm your friend\nI need you when you listen to me\nWeigh sand, Weigh sand\nBuy sand glass track\nClosing off, close off, close off\nOPEC dreams stock market close on the rock and roll scale stereo\nNo more partridge family dreams to the home land\nDivorce countries
```

So i can replace the split on "\n". Then would I just use a for loop to append each additional song? Line 0 happens to be an instrumental song btw.

edit2: this gives me AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

```
with open('Lyrics_Pavement.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data['songs'])


df1 = df.lyrics.str.split(pat="\n")

s = df1.loc[1]
lines = [i.strip() for i in s[1:-1].split(',')]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(lines)

print(df2)
```

Edit3: the code above actually did work, it was the dataframe I was referring to which was wrong. Either of the below solutions worked, I jsut changed the separation on commas to "\n". Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df1 = df.lyrics.str.split(pat="\n").explode()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting from your post that the lyrics in `df1` are just a long string, not an actual `list`?  If that's the case, then I would just use the builtin string methods to `split` this string up by the commas, and then reassemble into a dataframe:

```
s = "[It's the shouting, it's the shouting, It's the Dutchman, it's the Dutchman shout, Get it away, I don't need your shaft, It's the shouting, it's the shouting, It's the shouting, it's the Dutchman shout, Give it away, I don't need your shaft, (yes I do), It's the shouting, it's the shouting, It's the shouting, it's the Dutchman shout, Get it away, I don't need your shaft]"

lines = [i.strip() for i in s[1:-1].split(',')]
df = pd.DataFrame(lines)
```

Output:

```
                          0
0         It's the shouting
1         it's the shouting
2         It's the Dutchman
3   it's the Dutchman shout
4               Get it away
5   I don't need your shaft
6         It's the shouting
7         it's the shouting
8         It's the shouting
9   it's the Dutchman shout
10             Give it away
11  I don't need your shaft
12               (yes I do)
13        It's the shouting
14        it's the shouting
15        It's the shouting
16  it's the Dutchman shout
17              Get it away
18  I don't need your shaft
```

- `s[1:-1]` to omit the brackets
- `.split(',')` to split by commas
- `.strip()` to remove extra spaces

You could also do `lines = s[1:-1].split(', ')` if you know there's always *exactly* one comma + one space between each lyric.

If your full lyrics are part of `df1`, you could just `loc` (or w/e) to access the string and follow this answer.

Comment: ah similar answer to mine, i added the commas back in

Comment: I edited the main post to give some more clarity. When I try this I get the error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
I'm putting the code I'm using in the main post

Comment: actually I realize what I was doing wrong wrt this and the other solution. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

longstring = '''It's the shouting, it's the shouting, It's the Dutchman, it's the Dutchman shout, Get it away, I don't need your shaft, It's the shouting, it's the shouting, It's the shouting, it's the Dutchman shout, Give it away, I don't need your shaft, (yes I do), It's the shouting, it's the shouting, It's the shouting, it's the Dutchman shout, Get it away, I don't need your shaft'''


splitstring = [e.strip()+"," for e in longstring.split(",")]
splitstring[-1] = splitstring[-1].replace(",","")
df1 = pd.DataFrame(splitstring)
print(df1)  


#                           0
#0         It's the shouting,
#1         it's the shouting,
#2         It's the Dutchman,
#3   it's the Dutchman shout,
#4               Get it away,
#5   I don't need your shaft,
#6         It's the shouting,
#7         it's the shouting,
#8         It's the shouting,
#9   it's the Dutchman shout,
#10             Give it away,
#11  I don't need your shaft,
#12               (yes I do),
#13        It's the shouting,
#14        it's the shouting,
#15        It's the shouting,
#16  it's the Dutchman shout,
#17              Get it away,
#18   I don't need your shaft
```